# Android, canvas: How can I draw transparent circle without overprinting?

Tags: android, android-canvas

Stage 1. I have a background

[image: img 1]

Stage 2. I apply an overlay to background with a canvas to draw. First I fill the whole area with `canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(128,0,0,0))`

[image: img 2]

Then I need to draw a red transparent circle with `color.argb(128,255,0,0)` at a specified place, but I want circle red transparency replaced black filling transparency, not added. So, I wanna get this

[image: img 3]

but NOT this

[image: img 4]

How can I get it?

Comment: Answer some of your old questions and I'll tell you how to do it. :)

Comment: Hmmm... I've had some problems with answering my own questions earlier (not enough reputation or something about), but now it looks over. Thanks for tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use Canvas.clipPath before filling area with black color to exclude area, which will be used later by circle.

Comment: Just a precision - it requires a Region.Op.Difference as a second parameter to clipPath